# z3py, give random solution using seed

Tags: python, z3, z3py

```
from z3 import *

a = Int('a')

s = Solver()
s.add(a > 0)
set_option('smt.arith.random_initial_value', True)
set_option('auto_config', False)
set_option('smt.phase_selection', 5)
set_option('smt.random_seed', 1)

while s.check() == sat:
    m = s.model()
    print m[a]
    s.add(a != m[a])
```

The result is

```
1
2
3
4
5
...
```

How can I make the random work? **Please provide an example in Python using z3py...**
I already know how to do this in smt... But I am having a real hard time figuring it out how to translate the smt script to python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Z3py, random different solution generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60033332/z3py-random-different-solution-generation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a duplicate of [Z3py, random different solution generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60033332/z3py-random-different-solution-generation)

Are you trying to ask a different question? Please modify the question if so, if not you can delete it.